# Connect Router with Access Point by WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Is it possible to **connect a Router** with an Access Point by pure WiFi?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a technology called Wireless Distribution System http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System.

I don't think your specific router model has any custom firmware that can be flashed for WDS support.

Normally users would flash a different router firmware on to their router such as DD-WRT or Tomato, which would "unlock" WDS support.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your suggesting is possible without trying alternative firmware (DD-WRT, etc.) Although I could be wrong.

According to the manual for the TD-W8960NB WDS is possible with that model. Page 78 on the user manual has some more details.

For the TL-WA501G I suggest having a look at the following [link](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/article/?articleid=176).