# Connecting two TP-Link TL-WA701ND wirelessly

Tags: wireless-access-point

Having two access points  TP-Link TL-WA701ND, I would like to connect each one through wireless, not by an Ethernet cable. Could somebody point me out some link or guide on how to do it, please? I'm searching but can't find information.

Comment: I believe the answer in that case was "no", perhaps a better solution will be found this time.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with your hardware, but if I understood your question correctly, then these seem to be similar cases:

[Connecting multiple access points?](https://superuser.com/questions/506907/connecting-multiple-access-points)
[Connect router with access point by wifi?](https://superuser.com/questions/319368/connect-router-with-access-point-by-wifi)
[Can I connect my d-link to another access point?](https://superuser.com/questions/402088/can-i-connect-my-d-link-to-another-access-point)